# How does JavaScript know to execute the fail function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm working with jasmine and Supertest on an existing project.

```
let checkResult = require('./check-result');

it('should do something', function(done){
 request
      .post('/route')
      .expect(results => {
        expect(results).toBeTruthy(); 
      })
      .end(checkResult(done));
});
```

When I `console.log(done)` I get the following output: `{ [Function] fail: [Function] }`

Below is our checkResult module.

```
//check-result
module.exports = function checkResult(done){
  return function(seeIfThereIsError){
    if(seeIfThereIsError){
      done.fail(seeIfThereIsError)
    } else {
      done()
    }
  }
};
```

When an error occurs the `if(seeIfThereIsError)` block executes.

I have two questions:

1. When passing `done` into `checkResult` how does the returned function in `checkResult`'s `seeIfThereIsError` argument get populated?

   2. How is the signature `{ [Function] fail: [Function] }` get created?

In short how could I create an arbitrary example from scratch to understand the working parts (syntax) on how this all fits together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When passing `done` into `checkResult` how does the returned function in `checkResult`'s `seeIfThereIsError` argument get populated?

That function is passed to and called by `end`. I.e. `end` will pass a value to the function. In its simplest form it would look like:

```
request.end = function(callback) {
  callback(false);
};
```

> How is the signature `{ [Function] fail: [Function] }` get created?

How `console.log` represents functions isn't standardized. This output simply tells you that the value is a function object that has a custom property, `fail`, which is also a function.

If you want to create such a value yourself, this is how it could be done:

```
function done() {}
done.fail = function() {};
```

Whether `console.log(done)` gives you the output you saw depends on the browser and potentially other implementation specific heuristics.